# Exception while removing from list used by thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrentmodification

thats part of my code:

```
public List<Integer> _list = new ArrayList<>();

public void removeInteger(Integer i)
{
    _list.remove(i);
}

public class CheckThread implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        synchronized(_list) 
        {
            Iterator<Integer> it=_list.iterator(); 
            while(it.hasNext()) 
            {
                Integer i = it.next();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thread is running all the time(didnt write that part) and when i remove from list using removeInteger method, i have got ConcurrentModificationException. Any idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: Where are you invoking that `removeInteger()` from? And also, if you have the `iterator`, then you can remove using iterator. Using [`Iterator#remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove())

Comment: this thread is running every x seconds and iterating over the list. Thread is being run while program starts and removeInteger method is run right behind that. I didnt want to write whole program because its too big

Comment: @user1656546. If you are trying to remove elements while the Thread is already iterating your List, then you can't do that. You cannot modify a list that you are iterating upon. The only way would have been to remove it from the `iterator` while loop itself through iterator reference.

Comment: yeah thats what i am trying to do, remove from the list while thread is doing something with it. Can u write how it would need to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [it.remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) when you need to remove an element.

Comment: but i dont have iterator removeInteger method, and how would run() method know when to remove element?

Comment: you need to get into that thread and tell the iterator itself to remove the element. that is the way.

Comment: yeah then i would need to create second list with elements that have to be removed, any better way?

Answer (score 0):

**-** You **must** `synchronize` `remove()` method, else any otherwise **any other thread can access the list and try to remove element from it while other is putting element in it..**

```
 public  synchronized void removeInteger(Integer i)
{
    _list.remove(i);
}
```

Comment: tried that and also tried public void removeInteger(Integer i) { synchronize(_list) { _list.remove(i); }}. Same error

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to remove while iterating based on a condition write your condition inside the while loop and you can remove the objects using iterator's it.remove() like below

  ```
          Iterator<Integer> it=_list.iterator(); 
          while(it.hasNext()) 
          {
              Integer i = it.next();
              if(i<10){
                it.remove();
              }
          }
  ```

Comment: yeah yeah, as i wrote above i can make List of integers that can be deleted then delete them inside thread, but there is any better way?

Comment: Do you want the original list need not to be disturbed

Comment: i need it to be changing all the time even if thread is using it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try some thing like below ( you condition can be made better according to your requirements)

```
public void removeInteger(Integer i)
{
    Iterator iter = _list.iterator();
    int count=0;
    while(iter.hasNext()){
         if(count==i){
             _list.remove(i);
             break;
         }
    }
}
```